# Removing special characters in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

In google sheets this formula does not get rid of the special characters that are listed, which are these in this order [(),™®/|@#%*&`+:;<>{}\[\]?^$!=']. All these special characters are still there when the formula is run.

Here is the formula
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER('sheet'!E2716), "-", "")," ","-"), "[(),™®/|@#%*&`+:;<>{}\[\]?^$!=']",""),"--","-"), ".", "-")

The rest of the formula is fine, which below is what I am referring to
"-", "")," ","-")"--","-"), ".", "-").

All this can be left alone, its only that part that needs to be fixed.

Comment: your formula works fine to me. Can you share a sample string where it doesn't work?

Comment: It is fixed thank you for helping though